# Deploy a Rails app: LoadError: cannot load such file -- I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### What I wanted to do

I was trying to deploy my rails app and ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

#### Error message

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Template::Handlers::Erubis is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.2. Switch to ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::Erubi instead. (called from require at /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- I18n
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/config/initializers/class_extensions.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:104:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Running this command on my developer machine works fine. Running it on my server gives this error. I don’t know what’s different on the machines.

#### What I’ve tried

- including the `i18n` in the `Gemfile` like so
  `gem 'i18n', '~> 1.0'` – Didn’t help.
- installing the gem with `gem install i18n` prior to calling the rake task – Didn’t help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Downcasing the 'I' worked for me:

```
- require 'I18n'
+ require 'i18n'
```

Although I don't get why it doesn't work; running `require 'I18n'` in `irb` worked just fine.